# Information-theoretic interpretation of bijections

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, information-theory

Let us consider two sets $A$ and $B$. Suppose there exists a bijection $\phi:A\to B$ so that any $b\in B$ uniquely determines an element $a = \phi^{-1}(b)\in A$. In this sense, we can claim that the set $B$ gives us the `full information' of $A$ since every element in $A$ can be characterized by the element in $B$.

My question is, how can we interpret this bijection between two sets using information theory? How should we define probability distributions on $A$ and $B$ and use information theory to say `there is a bijection between $A$ and $B$'?

Answer (score 1):

Saying that $X$ is a random variable and $Y=f(x)$ where $f$ is a (measurable) bijection is equivalent to say that the conditional entropies are equal to zero, $H(Y|X)=H(X|Y)=0$, this also implies that the mutual information is equal to their entropies $I(X,Y)=H(X)=H(Y)$.

Comment: Hi Giovanni, thanks for the reply! In my question, I can define arbitrary random variables $X$ and $Y$ on the sets $A$ and $B$, respectively. Is there a specific way to determine the injection of the `deterministic' elements in $A$ and $B$?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'determine the injection'. However, if there is a uniform distribution over $A$ and if $f$ is injective (deterministic) map to $B$. If $f$ is injective then for a uniform random variable $X$ over the set $A$, $H(X)=\log |A| =\log |f(X)|$. which should be equal to $|B|$.

Comment: @lebesgue Thanks for the discussion. Maybe I should be more specific. Suppose we have r.v.s $X$ and $Y = f(x)$ where $f$ is a bijection. Then shall we say there also exists a bijection between the event spaces associated with these two r.v.s?